# I want to run flashing Leds with incandecsent bulb in a series

Tags: led, design, circuit-design

[image]I have my circuit built for flashing LEDs but i need them to work with an incandescent bulb so i can install them in the bottom of a flashlight. all of the power relays i have found to set it up for a series are far to big. Any ideas on how to make it work?

can i use resisters or possibly another small circuit to make it parallel but be triggered by a series?

The left side is what i tried, but obviously the forward voltage of the LEDs dont allow the incandescent lamp to light.

The right side is my thought on how to use a "series trigger" to activate an NPN resistor as a relay. But I am very new to this and not sure i have it correct.

The area from the switch to the bulb is sealed and unobtainable. that makes this a little more tricky than my skill level, that is why i am asking for help.

[image]

Comment: If I was in a worse mood I would vote to close this question as _unclear what you're asking_. The last sentence really makes no sense to me, do you think you can illustrate what you _have_ and what you _want_? There's a built-in circuit editor you can use.

Comment: Show us the circuit. You can probably replace the LED with a transistor capable of driving a typical halogen flashlight bulb, with an additional resistor or two.

Comment: You will get no useful suggestions until you post the schematic diagram of your current LED circuit.  We have no clue what you mean by "triggered by a series"?????  We have been using transistors do do this kind of switching for decades now. Relays are obsolete in those kinds of circuits.

Comment: I _think_ I understand it now, at least. Essentially you need to hook the LEDs in parallel with the battery, otherwise the voltage drop is too high. But you still want everything to turn on using the same toggle switch, and you can't reach the switch.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgxfJp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. This slightly unusual circuit might do what you want.*

How it works:

- Q1 is arranged as a common emitter transistor. When current flows into its base the transistor turns on and current can flow from the collector to the emitter.
- Normally a current limiting resistor is wired between the base and the supply. In this case we're using the lamp and all the lamp current will flow through the base.

You need to find an NPN transistor that can handle a base current of whatever normally flows through your lamp.

Your lamp will be a little dimmer as about 0.7 V will be dropped across the base-emitter junction of Q1.

> [OP's comment:] When the lamp is turned on by the switch, the positive energy is passed through the lamp to b on Q1.

Yes. We refer to it as "current flows through S1, LAMP1 and into the base of Q1 (and out through the emitter to return to the battery).

> That opens the connection from e to c on Q1.

Yes. We would usually say from c to e as that is the direction of current flow.

> But does it also connect e to b on Q1 to complete the lamp1 circuit?

Yes. Again current will flow from b to e. The base-emitter junction behaves like a regular diode in this configuration. It's the lamp current that will turn on the transistor.

> Also, would I need a resister on Q1?

Yes. You need a base resistor but you already have one - LAMP1. It's a low value and it will pass a higher current than would be normal in a transistor switch.

Comment: Ok, so when the lamp is turned on by the switch, the positive energy is passed through the lamp to b on Q1. That opens the connection from e to c on Q1. but does it also connect e to b on Q1 to complete the lamp1 circuit? Also, would i need a resister on Q1?

Comment: Answered in the question.

Comment: awesome cant wait to try this. I will pick up the parts and breadboard it tonight and let you know how it goes!!

Comment: Measure the lamp current first. The choice of transistor will depend on that.

Comment: ok the lamp is 4.8v .75a 3.6w but when wiring them up by the diagram above the emitter is always live. And the bulb doesn't light,  i used an npn 2n3904, the smallest i was able to source locally.

Comment: (1) You have selected the wrong transistor and it has failed. If you read the [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/2N3904.pdf) you will see that the max collector current is 200 mA. You are trying to run 750 mA through it. I cautioned you that you would need to find a transistor that will handle that much current **in the base**. (2) "_The emitter is always live_" doesn't make sense. You need to explain where you're measuring the voltage.

Comment: What i meant was the LEDs stay on even with the base disconnected. 
The only other NPN transistors i could source locally was 2n4401 and 2n222a but they are only 600mA, you are saying i need to find transistors that are 750mA or more?

Comment: Sorry, @Mudacon, but you are trying to solve this problem with no understanding of how transistors work. You need to forget your flashing LEDs for a while and do some study, learn the important parameters of the transistor and how basic transistor switching circuits work. This site is intended to _assist_ with electrical engineering design questions and not provide complete designs to folk who haven't studied the subject. With a bit of study you will understand my answer and comments more fully. Return with a new question at that stage.

Comment: Figured it out, your solution worked flawlessly. I put the transistor into the breadboard to far and the contacts were all touching. It works exactly as you said it would. It wasn't a basic understanding of transistors that failed me, it seems it was basic understanding of breadboards, lol. Thank you for your assistance!!

Comment: Good. If it lasts a day then accept my answer!

Comment: ok maybe my basic understanding of transistors is faulty. Why wouldn't it last? (Thank you for your patience, I AM new to this and learning as fast as i can due purely to necessity, and curiosity)

Answer (score 0):

You would either replace the led with a npn transistor, appropriately sized for your incandescent bulb load, or you would connect the transistor in parallel with one of the leds. Highly depends on your setup.

Comment: i need both leds however, can I use the NPN resistor as a relay and use the same power source to power it? (i will draw the circuit idea if needed)

Comment: It is needed...

Comment: edited my original post to display what i am working with